# Can top output show more than 100% in %MEM against a process?

Tags: sip-server

Can the %MEM value for a process show more than 100% in top output?Is this ever possible?

Comment: No this is related to a Opensips,SIP server.

Comment: If it's not programming related, you shouldn't post it here. There are other sites that would be more suitable, for example serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the value shown is the percentage of physical memory excluding swap, but a program can use more than this if it also uses swap.

Comment: But if the system is not swapping then i guess more than 100% value in %MEM is impossible. Am i right?